# How to bin frequency above and below a value

Tags: r, histogram

There are quite a few question on binning in R but I have not come across this particular problem. I have a list of numbers and want to bin the frequency <=2 and >2.

To clarify I need a histogram with two bins composed of values <=2 and >2.

My variable is

```
Var = a
 [1] 2 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 3 3 5 1 4 4 0 3 4 1 0 3 3 0 0 1 3 2 6 2 2 2 1
[35] 0 2 3 2 0 0 0 0 3 2 2 4 3 2 2 0 4 1 0 1 3 1 4 3 1 2 6 7 6 1 2 2 4 5
[69] 3 0 6 5 2 0 7 1 7 3 1 4 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 4 2 0 3 3 2 2 2 5 3 2 5 2 5
```

I can organize into the numbers into a table to see the frequency of each number

```
a = table(var)

        Var1     Freq
    1   0     15
    2   1     23
    3   2     25
    4   3     17
    5   4     9
    6   5     6
    7   6     4
    8   7     3
```

Now how do I bin for values <=2 and >2?

Comment: That is an interesting suggestion. I did something similar with 'GreaterThan2= sum(var>2); 
 lessThan2= sum(var<=2) 
 x = cbind(GreaterThan2, lessThan2); 
 hist(x)'

But what results is two bins with a frequency of 1 at the number of instances below and above 2

Comment: I dont think you want a histogram. Try it with `barplot`. ie `barplot(table(var<=2))`

Comment: Thank us @user20650, that is what I was looking for. Could you please summit it as an answer as it is very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are splitting your vector in two, you can create the groups by applying the inequality statements directly to the vector. To plot the table you can use `barplot` .

```
set.seed(1)     
var <- sample(1:10, 100, T)

(tab <- table(var<=2))
#FALSE  TRUE 
#   87    13 

barplot(tab)
```

Or directly

```
barplot(table(var<=2))
```

For more categories, the vector can be categorised using `cut`

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
ct  <- cut(a, breaks = c(0, 2, max(a)), include.lowest=TRUE, labels=c("<=2", ">2"))
## [1] <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 >2  <=2 >2  >2  >2  <=2 >2  >2  <=2
## [19] >2  >2  <=2 <=2 >2  >2  <=2 <=2 <=2 >2  <=2 >2  <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2
## [37] >2  <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 >2  <=2 <=2 >2  >2  <=2 <=2 <=2 >2  <=2 <=2 <=2
## [55] >2  <=2 >2  >2  <=2 <=2 >2  >2  >2  <=2 <=2 <=2 >2  >2  >2  <=2 >2  >2 
## [73] <=2 <=2 >2  <=2 >2  >2  <=2 >2  <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 <=2 >2  <=2
## [91] <=2 >2  >2  <=2 <=2 <=2 >2  >2  <=2 >2  <=2 >2 
## Levels: <=2 >2

table(ct)
## ct
## <=2  >2 
## 63   39
```

You can plot it using `barplot` as @user20650 suggested:

```
barplot(table(ct))
```

[image]